# Python3 - What is correct Syntax? a = b(string, integer)

Tags: string, integer

I've been studying for 30 hours straight and probably should rest, but I want to finish this.  What have I done wrong?

## CONSTRUCTOR

```
def __init__(self, street_address, city, state, zipcode, bedrooms, bathrooms, squarefeet, modelname, salestatus):
    self.street_address = street_address
    self.city = city
    self.state = state
    self.zipcode = zipcode
    self.bedrooms = bedrooms
    self.bathrooms = bathrooms
    self.squarefeet = squarefeet + 'square feet'
    self.modelname = modelname
    self.salestatus = salestatus
```

## 1. ADD HOME

```
def add_home(self):
    street_address = input('Enter street address: ')
    city = input('Enter city: ')
    state = input('Enter state: ')
    zipcode = int(input('Enter zip code: '))
    bedrooms = int(input('Enter number of bedrooms: '))
    bathrooms = int(input('Enter number of baths: '))
    squarefeet = int(input('Enter square footage: '))
    modelname = input('What is the model?: ')
    salestatus = input('Is the home sold, available, or under contract?: ')

    home_info = Home_Inventory(street_address, city, state, int(zipcode), int(bedrooms), int(bathrooms), int(squarefeet) + ' square feet', modelname, salestatus)
    full_address = (street_address, city, state, int(zipcode)
    home_stats = (int(bedrooms), int(bathrooms), int(squarefeet) + ' square feet', modelname, salestatus)
    Allhomes = {full_address: home_stats}

    print('Home has been added successfully.')
```

Comment: You’ll have to explain what is wrong. What should this code do? What does it do instead?

Comment: You dumped your code here with no explanations whatsoever - that's pretty wrong, because you're not likely to get a constructive and helpful answer on this type of question.